# Regex for only changing expression between sth in R

Tags: r, regex

I have some general sentence,

```
\r\n sth ~ sth\r\nsth ~ sth ~ \r\n
```

What I want to do is just make \r\n to nothing like ""

So the result is

```
\r\n sth ~ sthsth ~ sth ~ \r\n
```

If I use regex

```
gsub("\\S\r\n\\S","\\S\\S",string)
```

Then the result is ( the example is rolling\r\nstones )

```
\r\n sth ~ rollinSStones ~ sth ~ \r\n
```

Is there any method to leave the string :

```
\r\n sth ~ rollingstones ~ sth ~ \r\n
```

I need a general solution to leave the other \r\n just \r\n

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\\b` instead of `\\S`:

```
gsub("\\b\r\n\\b", "", "\r\n sth ~ sth\r\nsth ~ sth ~ \r\n")
#[1] "\r\n sth ~ sthsth ~ sth ~ \r\n"
```

or to come close to what you might have wanted with `gsub("\\S\r\n\\S","\\S\\S",string)`

```
gsub("(\\S)\r\n(\\S)", "\\1\\2", "\r\n sth ~ sth\r\nsth ~ sth ~ \r\n")
#[1] "\r\n sth ~ sthsth ~ sth ~ \r\n"
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. It did really help for me

Answer (score 0):

We can use positive lookahead and lookbehind regex :

```
string <- '\r\n sth ~ sth\r\nsth ~ sth ~ \r\n'

gsub("(?<=\\S)\r\n(?=\\S)","",string, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "\r\n sth ~ sthsth ~ sth ~ \r\n"
```

We can use the same regex in `str_remove` from `stringr`

```
stringr::str_remove(string, '(?<=\\S)\r\n(?=\\S)')
```

This will remove only `'/r/n'` from the string where it is not followed by a whitespace keeping the non-whitespace character as it is.

Comment: Thanks for reply, It was helping me but please understand I can give green check mark only one of you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub`with double backreference:

```
gsub("(sth)\r\n(sth)", "\\1\\2", string)
#[1] "\r\n sth ~ sthsth ~ sth ~ \r\n"
```

`\\1` captures the first capturing group, which is `(sth)`

`\\2` captures te second capturing group, which is (the second) `(sth)`

Comment: Thanks for giving me intuitive explanation, but please understand I can choose only one reply in the system. Your reply also helped me a lot.